# Does the dart http2 package allow for multiple get requests and cache the responses?

Tags: dart, http, caching, request, http2

I want to fetch multiple images and audio files on one tcp connection. Is that possible with the current state of the[http2](https://pub.dev/documentation/http2/latest/) package and how would that be done?

Also, if it is possible. If I later request the same image or audio file over http1 but it was cached when I made the requests earlier with http2, will it then get it from cache?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to fetch multiple images and audio files over a single TCP connection.

These are the main points you need to keep in mind

- Create a `Client` instance from the `http2` package.
- Construct multiple `Request` objects for the resources you want to
  fetch.
- Use the `client.send()` method to send each request. This will
  pipeline them over the same TCP connection.
- The responses will stream back asynchronously.

For caching, HTTP/2 in Dart works similar to other implementations - cached resources can be retrieved over HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 interchangeably.